# How to save files in specific folder

Tags: vb6

I have used the below code to save files in current path , however i want to create folder and save all files as backup in this folder like c:\project\backup
any help please

```
Path = App.Path
```

Comment: Google up the vb6 command `MkDir`.  Lots of examples and explanations on SO and other sites.

Comment: Please let me know the code to complete the process

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR].  All your past questions have a score of 0 or less.  Which means you are either asking the wrong questions (such as this one where the answer is *easily* found with a simple Google search) or you are asking in the wrong way (such as this one which shows no effort at all).  Perhaps browse the [help] too.  `Please let me know the code`  Thats **not** what the site is about.

Comment: @Plutonix you mean we are not a code-writing service????

Comment: This site is to exchange experience with people and helps in best way !

Comment: Yes and you have not yet figured out the *best way* part: 4 of your 5 posts are judged *bad* and one is zero (worthless).  So read [ask] and take the [TOUR] to work out what the site is *really* about

Answer (score 0):

Use FileSystemObject(FSO). You can create directory and files using FileSystemObject. You will be able to delete or copy files using FileSystemObject.

To enable FileSystemObject just goto project reference and check Microsoft Scripting Runtime. For more info about FileSystemObject go to [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/186118/how-to-use-filesystemobject-with-visual-basic).